# Increasing antlr performance

Tags: python, antlr, antlr4

I am building a process that will need to parse ~150 million queries a day from Oracle databases. I am using the PlSql grammar for antlr here: https://github.com/antlr/grammars-v4/blob/master/plsql/PlSqlParser.g4

Antlr generates a Lexer with 20k lines and a parser with 100k lines.

Here is an example of parsing a very simple select statement

```
from antlr4 import *
from antlr4.tree.Tree import TerminalNode
from plsql import PlSqlLexer, PlSqlParserListener, PlSqlParser
import datetime


def handleTree(tree, lvl=0):
    for child in tree.getChildren():
        if isinstance(child, TerminalNode):
            print(lvl*'│ ' + '└─', child)
        else:
            handleTree(child, lvl+1)


class KeyPrinter(PlSqlParserListener.PlSqlParserListener):
    def enterSelect_statement(self, ctx):
        handleTree(ctx, 0)


def main():
    now = datetime.datetime.now()
    i_stream = InputStream(str.upper("""SELECT col1 FROM table1"""))

    lexer = PlSqlLexer.PlSqlLexer(i_stream)
    t_stream = CommonTokenStream(lexer)
    parser = PlSqlParser.PlSqlParser(t_stream)
    tree = parser.sql_script()

    printer = KeyPrinter()
    walker = ParseTreeWalker()
    walker.walk(printer, tree)

    print(datetime.datetime.now()-now)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

output:

```
│ │ │ └─ SELECT
│ │ │ │ │ │ │ │ │ │ │ │ │ │ │ │ │ │ │ └─ COL1
│ │ │ │ └─ FROM
│ │ │ │ │ │ │ │ │ │ │ │ │ └─ TABLE1
0:00:36.104422
```

It takes 36 seconds to parse this simple query. What are my options to increase performance? Is a different language better?

- This will eventually be a REST micro-service deployed on Openshift. I can throw alot of hardware at it across many pods, but the amount i would need right now is unfeasible.

Comment: could you use something like [psqlparse](https://github.com/alculquicondor/psqlparse) to do the parsing instead?  should be able to parse queries like that in much less than a millisecond, but is obviously postgres syntax rather than oracle

Comment: I saw it, Ill definitely give it a try and check the miss rate if its thats much faster. We can work with anything >80% success

Comment: it's about 100microseconds for me on your trivial query, about 250 if I use a more complicated query using CTEs and joins.  you've got the source, so could try hacking the grammar

Comment: Side note: the python runtime for ANTLR4 is known to be very slow. If you can try a different target (C++ being the fastest). I measure 150µs for your query with a MySQL grammar (using the C++ target).